# swiper js with tabs only shows first tabs images

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, swiper.js

I'm trying to show a page with having to two tabs: `After`, and `Before`. each one have several images, im trying to make it with swiper js, but the problem is that it only shows the first tabs(After) images in the before tabs
here is my html page:

```
            <div class="wrapper row" id="project_details">              
                <div class="preview col-md-6">
                  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                      <button class="nav-link active" id="after-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#after" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="after" aria-selected="true">After</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                      <button class="nav-link" id="before-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#before" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="before" aria-selected="false">Before</button>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  
                  <div class="tab-pane fade show active text-dark" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="after-tab">
                    <div class="swiper mySwiper" id="preview-pic-after">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper after-imgs" id="after-id">
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="before-tab" id="before-tab">
                    <div class="swiper mySwiper" id="preview-pic-before">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper before-imgs" id="before-id">
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                                
                </div>
            some other details ..
            </div>
```

and my jquery code:

```
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:api_url,
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(response){
                console.log(response.list_imgs)                
                console.log('test')
                var img_after_dv = '';
                var img_before_dv='';

                for (let index = 0; index < response.list_imgs.length; index++) {
                    if(response.list_imgs[index]['category'] == 'After'){

                        console.log('after')

                        console.log(response.list_imgs[index])

                        img_after_dv+=`
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <img src="${response.list_imgs[index]['img']}" />
                        </div>`
                    }

                }
                document.getElementById('after-id').innerHTML += img_after_dv

                for (let index = 0; index < response.list_imgs.length; index++) {

                    if (response.list_imgs[index]['category'] == 'Before') {
                        console.log('before')
                        console.log(response.list_imgs[index])

                        img_before_dv+=`
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <img src="${response.list_imgs[index]['img']}" />
                        </div>`                        
                    }    


                }

                document.getElementById('before-id').innerHTML += img_before_dv

            }

        })
```

and swiper js:

```
        var afterSwiper = new Swiper("#preview-pic-after", {
            effect: "coverflow",
            grabCursor: true,
            centeredSlides: true,
            slidesPerView: "auto",
            coverflowEffect: {
              rotate: 50,
              stretch: 0,
              depth: 100,
              modifier: 1,
              slideShadows: true,
            },
            pagination: {
              el: ".swiper-pagination",
            },
          });

          var beforeSwiper = new Swiper("#preview-pic-before", {
            effect: "coverflow",
            grabCursor: true,
            centeredSlides: true,
            slidesPerView: "auto",
            coverflowEffect: {
              rotate: 50,
              stretch: 0,
              depth: 100,
              modifier: 1,
              slideShadows: true,
            },
            pagination: {
              el: ".swiper-pagination",
            },
          });
```

the issues is that still i get the same images for before tab, which it has its own images!

Thank you for your help